# Modifying date using Selenium and Python on Google Travel website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I am trying to create a simple web scraper through which I can scrape rates of a hotel for 5 consecutive dates. However using Selenium, I am unable to navigate into the calendar dropdown to select the required date or directly insert the date I want into the date input box.
[Element I want to automate marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peNnb.png)

How do I proceed?

Link for website: https://www.google.com/travel/search

I tried using the class for the div and input tags, but that returned an 'elementclickinterceptedexception' error.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 


checkin_query= ['Tue, Aug 1', 'Wed, Aug 2', 'Thu, Aug 3']
search_query= ['JW Marriott Mumbai', 'Sofitel Mumbai']

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')

for j in range(len(checkin_query)):
    for i in range(len(search_query)):
        browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", options= options)
        browser.get('http://www.google.com/travel/search')

        searchElement = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@placeholder,"Search for places, hotels and more")]')
        checkinElement = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@placeholder,"Check-in")]')
    
        checkinElement.send_keys(search_query[j])

        searchElement.clear()
        searchElement.send_keys(search_query[i])
        time.sleep(2)

        dropdownElement= browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[contains(@role,"option")]').click()
```

I have attached the code snippet. Apart from the date insertion option, everything works fine

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I have modified the query to add the piece of code I tried

Comment: `webdriver` is not defined.   the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>[You *could* keep clicking the next-day button until the value matched the desired check-in date, but I can see why you might want to avoid such an inefficient method...]</sub>

> ```py
>         checkinElement.send_keys(search_query[j])
> ```

There are a couple of issues with what you're trying to do here:

- first off, you probably want **`checkin_query[j]`** and the *`search_query`* was just a typo...
- when I tried your code, it did input your value, but it added onto whatever was already there, so you need to clear the field first

  - unfortunately, `checkinElement.click()`+`checkinElement.clear()` didn't seem to be working [although you can give it a try - it could be a version problem...]

  So I tried using `Keys` instead and that worked for me

  ```py
  # from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

          checkinElement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
          checkinElement.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
          checkinElement.send_keys(checkin_query[j])
  ```